# Unity - a 3d slider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, I'm trying to make a 3d slider in C# in Unity where the user can modify the max and min values and get the current value as the knob moves up and down the slider -

[image]

To do this, I thought I'd need a sort of map function, to map the knob's actual position to the max and min values, and prevent the sliding from going over that. Input is controlled via a pointer, so what I've tried so far is:

```
 public void OnClickDown()
    {
        if (ModeManager.GameMode == ModeManager.Mode.Preview)
        {
            isSelected = true;
        }
    }
    public void OnUnhover()
    {
        if (ModeManager.GameMode == ModeManager.Mode.Preview)
        {
            isSelected = false;
        }
    }

    public float scale(float OldMin, float OldMax, float NewMin, float NewMax, float OldValue)
    {

        float OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin);
        float NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin);
        float NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin;

        return (NewValue);
    }
```

Either trying it manually with bounds:

```
private void Update()
    {
        
        if (isSelected)
        {
            if(pointer.keyboardCollider.transform.position.x <= 0.1744 && pointer.keyboardCollider.transform.position.x > -0.1879)
            {
                knob.transform.position = new Vector3(pointer.keyboardCollider.transform.position.x, knob.transform.position.y, knob.transform.position.z);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or with the scale / map function:

```
//In Update()
knob.transform.position = new Vector3(scale(minValue, maxValue, -0.185f, 0.1744f, pointer.keyboardCollider.transform.position.x), knob.transform.position.y, knob.transform.position.z);
```

Neither works or gives consistent results. How can I create this 3d slider - making sure the knob moves only on the track specifically?

Comment: You can `Clamp` the value between the min and max values and convert a coordinate to the rect space of your slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a game object for both the min point of the slider bar and the max point of the slider bar.  This makes it easier to visualize and change, but is in no way a requirement.  The below examples will assume minPoint and maxPoint are transforms.

You can easily set the position of the knob using Lerp (assume x axis)

```
knob.position.x = Mathf.Lerp(minPoint.position.x, maxPoint.position.x, value01);
```

To get the value01 from the knob position (assume x axis)

```
1f / ((maxPoint.position.x - minPoint.position.x) / (knob.position.x - minPoint.position.x));
```

Comment: Ok - but how do I factor in the pointer location / lock the position of the knob to that pointer location? What is value01 ?

Comment: value01 is a float between 0 and 1.  If you replace knob.position.x in the 2nd snippit with the pointer x (in world space), it will give you the value you can use in the lerp.  Make sure to clamp that value between 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks. There's a bit of jumpiness - even when I enlarge the collider on the knob. Is there a way to add in some tolerance / make sure the knob doesnt sometimes jump to 0 or 1?

Comment: You can smooth the value using another lerp.  You will need 3 global floats, currentValue, targetValue, and a smoothing value.  You would store the value from the first code snippit as targetValue.  Set the current value using `currentValue = Mathf.Lerp(currentValue, targetValue, Time.deltaTime * smoothing)`.  Then set the knob position to currentValue.  If there is too much smoothing it will look and feel unnatural, so you may need to play with the value a bit.